# *apply for combinations of two vectors

Tags: r

### Question

Which of the apply functions can I use to go from Data to Result?

### Data

```
start      <- "My name is"
name.first <- c("John","Jane")
name.last  <- c("Doe","Smith")
end        <- "and I am a person."
```

### Desired Result

```
result.1 <- c("My name is John Doe and I am a person",
              "My name is Jane Doe and I am a person",
              "My name is John Smith and I am a person",
              "My name is Jane Smith and I am a person")

result.2 <- as.list(desired.1)
```

### My feeble attemp...

I thought `mapply` would do the trick here, but it only produces two outputs, instead of four that I'd like.

```
> mapply(function(x,y, start, end) paste(start, x, y, end, sep = " "),
+        name.first, 
+        name.last, 
+        MoreArgs = list(start, end),
+        USE.NAMES = FALSE)
[1] "My name is John Doe and I am a person."  
[2] "My name is Jane Smith and I am a person."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `outer` and `paste`

```
start <- "My name is"
name.first <- c("John", "Jane")
name.last <- c("Doe", "Smith")
end <- "and I am a person."

as.vector(outer(name.first, name.last, paste))
## [1] "John Doe"   "Jane Doe"   "John Smith" "Jane Smith"

paste("My name is ", as.vector(outer(name.first, name.last, paste)))
## [1] "My name is  John Doe"   "My name is  Jane Doe"   "My name is  John Smith" "My name is  Jane Smith"

paste("My name is ", as.vector(outer(name.first, name.last, paste)), " and I am a person")
## [1] "My name is  John Doe  and I am a person"   "My name is  Jane Doe  and I am a person"  
## [3] "My name is  John Smith  and I am a person" "My name is  Jane Smith  and I am a person"

as.list(paste("My name is ", as.vector(outer(name.first, name.last, paste)), " and I am a person"))
## [[1]]
## [1] "My name is  John Doe  and I am a person"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "My name is  Jane Doe  and I am a person"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "My name is  John Smith  and I am a person"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "My name is  Jane Smith  and I am a person"
##
```

As you saw in your attempt, `mapply` will match only corresponding elements of it's input vector i.e. for first `iteration` it will use first elements of all input vectors, for second `iteration` it will use second elements of all input vectors and so on.

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't know about the outer function. Also, I was able to do it with a single call to paste by using an anonymous function in outer, like this: `as.vector(outer(name.first, name.last, function(x,y,start,end) paste(start,x,y,end), start, end))`

Answer (score 2):

```
paste( start = "My name is",
        apply( expand.grid(name.first = c("John","Jane"),
                           name.last  = c("Doe","Smith"), 
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
               1, paste, collapse=" "),
        end  = "and I am a person.")

[1] "My name is John Doe and I am a person."   "My name is Jane Doe and I am a person."  
[3] "My name is John Smith and I am a person." "My name is Jane Smith and I am a person."
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the `expand.grid` function! I had used it before to solve something like this, but could NOT recall its name.